# CQL3 Connection with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm implementing a simple Java program that connects to a remote Cassandra cluster. I have followed all the instructions based on questions and answers on this forum but still getting errors. Below is the java Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DataReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Connection con = null;
  try {
   Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://62.31.3.185:9160/proto");

   String query = "SELECT user_name, password, first_name, last_name, session_token   
          FROM users WHERE user_name=tigris";
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

   while (result.next()) {
      System.out.println(result.getString("user_name"));
      System.out.println(result.getString("password"));
      System.out.println(result.getString("first_name"));
      System.out.println(result.getString("last_name"));
      System.out.println(result.getString("session_token"));
   }

 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
   if (con != null) {
   try {
     con.close();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
     con = null;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Below is the stack trace:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input ''
'SELECT user_name, password, first_name, last_name, session_token FROM users WHERE user_name=tigris'
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:181)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.executeQuery(CassandraStatement.java:229)
        at CqlConnection.main(CqlConnection.java:19)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '')
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:37849)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1562)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1547)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:468)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:494)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:164)
        ... 2 more

I have the following libraries in my classpath:

cassandra-clientutil-1.2.6
cassandra-clientutil-2.0.7
cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5
cassandra-thrift-1.2.6
guava-17.0
libthrift-0.9.0

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to look into using a Cassandra CQL driver (e.g. [DataStax Java Driver](http://github.com/datastax/java-driver) rather than the JDBC library that was not updated in a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that this is your problem:

```
WHERE user_name=tigris
```

If you were to try that from `cqlsh` you would have to put single quotes around "tigris," like this:

```
WHERE user_name='tigris'
```

And that's what you'll have to do to get this to work here.

Of course, you could avoid this problem completely if you used prepared statements and bound variables.  Here is how that would look:

```
String query = "SELECT user_name, password, first_name, last_name, session_token   
      FROM users WHERE user_name=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

stmt.setString(1, "tigris");
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
```